# Get profit percent of last closed trades in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

im struglin to get the profit percent for a chosen number of last closed trades, any help is apreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate a specific trades profit by using the closed trade built ins. Here is a custom function for you

```
strategy_closedtrades_percent_profit(trade_num) =>
    posVal = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(trade_num) * math.abs(strategy.closedtrades.size(trade_num))
    profit = strategy.closedtrades.profit(trade_num)
    profitInPercent = profit / posVal *100
```

Cheers and best of luck with your coding and trading

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately give me this error: "Syntax error at input '=>'."

Comment: Make sure you are using version 5 Pine. It is the newest version

Comment: Thanks, i convert it to v5.
How can i change it for last 10 trades for example?

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Bjorgum shows the first trade only. You have to calculate `trade_num` differently so you count from the back (last trade closed). This will do it:

```
total_trades = strategy.closedtrades - 1
trade_num = 1
show_trade = total_trades - trade_num

posVal = strategy.closedtrades.entry_price(trade_num) * math.abs(strategy.closedtrades.size(trade_num))
profit = strategy.closedtrades.profit(trade_num)
profitInPercent = profit / posVal *100
```